# How do I reorder the fields/columns in a SharePoint view?

Tags: sharepoint

I'm adding a new field to a list and view. To add the field to the view, I'm using this code:

```
view.ViewFields.Add("My New Field");
```

However this just tacks it on to the end of the view. How do I add the field to a particular column, or rearrange the field order? view.ViewFields is an SPViewFieldCollection object that inherits from SPBaseCollection and there are no Insert / Reverse / Sort / RemoveAt methods available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found removing all items from the list and readding them in the order that I'd like works well (although a little drastic). Here is the code I'm using:

```
string[] fieldNames = new string[] { "Title", "My New Field", "Modified", "Created" };
SPViewFieldCollection viewFields = view.ViewFields;
viewFields.DeleteAll();
foreach (string fieldName in fieldNames)
{
    viewFields.Add(fieldName);
}
view.Update();
```

Comment: If you remove the field/column from the list, you also lose its content. Sometimes that's a very, very bad thing (and heck, it needs to be noted!)

Comment: @user this is not the case. He is removing fields from a list view, not from the list itself

Answer (score 1):

You can use the default method:

```
    int newFieldOrderIndex = 1;
    SPViewFieldCollection viewFields = view.ViewFields;
    viewFields.MoveFieldTo(fieldName, newFieldOrderIndex);
    view.Update();
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spviewfieldcollection.movefieldto.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the follow method to reorder the field

```
 string reorderMethod = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?> 
                          <Method ID=""0,REORDERFIELDS""> 
                          <SetList Scope=""Request"">{0}</SetList>  
                          <SetVar Name=""Cmd"">REORDERFIELDS</SetVar>  
                          <SetVar Name=""ReorderedFields"">{1}</SetVar>  
                          <SetVar Name=""owshiddenversion"">{2}</SetVar>  
                          </Method>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I had two different lists and similar view. I wanted to update destination list view field order if user change order in source view.

```
ViewFieldCollection srcViewFields = srcView.ViewFields;
ViewFieldCollection destViewFields = destView.ViewFields;

var srcArray = srcViewFields.ToArray<string>();
var destArray = destViewFields.ToArray<string>();

foreach (var item in destArray)
{
    destViewFields.MoveFieldTo(item, Array.IndexOf(srcArray, item));
    destView.Update();
}
```

Comment: Would you lease be more specific about the answer, a little explnatation would be nice.